# Procmail recipe - If no dkim signature then forward to .spam

Tags: ubuntu, dkim, procmail, opendkim

Having read through the documentation at http://pm-doc.sourceforge.net/doc/
i cannot find an answer.

I want to use procmail to place mail without dkim into user's spam folder. I have found many articles about dkim filtering, none of which explain the desired behaviour.

(Environment: virtualmin, procmail, spamassasin, postfix, ubuntu 18.04 Server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will trigger on any message which lacks a `DKIM-Signature:` header. There is no attempt as such to validate the DKIM signature (which would make more sense to perform on the mail server anyway; I'm guessing yours might already be doing this.)

```
:0
* ! ^DKIM-Signature:
.spam
```

In Procmail terminology, this is *saving* (or *sorting* or *storing*) the message to a folder (or mailbox); to *forward* a message means to send it on to a different email address.

Comment: This should be trivial to understand with even the most basic understanding of Procmail syntax. I find it hard to imagine that you didn't come up with something like this on your own.

Comment: Looking at it makes absolute sense. But as a complete novice had missed the simplicity of it. Regards